# Python pandas - timeseries merge of two df with some different timestamps and refill of missing timestamps with last values

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two datasets:
df1 = old saved data as .csv file and loaded with pandas with the following structure:

df1:

```
                    Date     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0    2019-12-13 11:29:00  19.6804  19.6955  19.6755  19.6804     744
1    2019-12-13 11:27:00  19.6600  19.6600  19.6400  19.6400      64
.
.
.
305  2019-12-09 03:19:00  19.3400  19.4000  19.3400  19.4000    1604
306  2019-12-09 03:00:00  19.4000  19.4000  19.4000  19.4000       0
```

..............................................................................................

df2 = new data in pandas format with the same structure but other timestamps:

df2:

```
                    Date   Open   High    Low  Close  Volume
0    2019-12-16 04:32:00  19.60  19.60  19.60  19.60     204
1    2019-12-16 04:24:00  19.62  19.62  19.62  19.62     200
.
.
.
249  2019-12-10 03:08:00  19.20  19.20  19.12  19.12     235
250  2019-12-10 03:00:00  19.30  19.30  19.30  19.30       0
```

In df1 are some of datasets of df2, but df2 is newer.
I don't want to lose the old datasets and merge it with the new datasets according to the date.
How can I link the datasets according to the date into one data (df12) with pandas?
How I can refill the new dataset (df_accu) with missing datasets 
like:

df12:

```
    Date                  Open              High              Low               Close             Volume
0    2019-12-13 11:29:00  19.6804           19.6955           19.6755           19.6804           744
1    2019-12-13 11:28:00  [previous value]  [previous value]  [previous value]  [previous value]  0
2    2019-12-13 11:27:00  19.6600           19.6600           19.6400           19.6400           64
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd concatenate both `df1` and `df2` to start, then build a new series with all dates and merge it back to the result of concatenating both `df1` and `df2` and fill all `nan`. My setup has only one value column for simplicity, but the code should run even with more than one value columns.

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-12-13 11:29:00', '2019-12-09 03:19:00', '2019-12-09 03:00:00'], 'Value': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-12-16 04:32:00', '2019-12-10 03:00:00', '2019-12-10 03:08:00'], 'Value': [1, 2, 3]})
```

If there are no duplicate dates between both `df1` and `df2` just calling `pd.concat` on them should do the trick. The `assign` call can be omitted if your `'Date'` columns are already `datetime`:

```
df12 = pd.concat((df1, df2))
df12 = df12.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df12['Date']))
```

If there are duplicates, drop them after concatenating, watch out for the `keep` argument as that will dictate whether were keeping the values of `df1` or from `df2`:

```
df12 = df12.drop_duplicates('Date', keep='first') # if keeping values from df1
df12 = df12.drop_duplicates('Date', keep='last') # if keeping values from df2
```

For the second part, we build a new series with all possible dates, and merge it back to the original `df12`. Then we sort by date and fill all `nan` values with the previous value (I'm assuming that by 'previous_value' you mean the value from the previous date, but if that's no the case sort by `'Date'` descending instead):

```
s1 = pd.Series(
    pd.date_range(df12['Date'].min(), df12['Date'].max(), freq='T'), # freq 'T' = minutes, I'm assuming this given your example
    name='Date'
) 

df12 = df12.merge(s1, 'outer', left_on='Date', right_on='Date').sort_values('Date')
df12[['Value']] = df12[['Value']].fillna(method='ffill')
# Uncomment the next line to fill the values in 'Volume' col with 0 instead of the previous one
# df12[['Volume']] = df12[['Volume']].fillna(0)
```

The result:

```
>>> df12
                     Date  Value
0     2019-12-09 03:00:00    3.0
1     2019-12-09 03:01:00    3.0
2     2019-12-09 03:02:00    3.0
3     2019-12-09 03:03:00    3.0
4     2019-12-09 03:04:00    3.0
...                   ...    ...
10168 2019-12-16 04:28:00    1.0
10169 2019-12-16 04:29:00    1.0
10170 2019-12-16 04:30:00    1.0
10171 2019-12-16 04:31:00    1.0
10172 2019-12-16 04:32:00    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the last value, Volume should not be the previous value, but zero.

Comment: Didn't notice this comment as it was left as a new answer instead of a comment to my own answer. I've added a line as well as tweaked another one to support filling values with `0` in the Volume col.